# spray json parsing for an object with more than 22 attributes

Tags: json, scala, parsing, spray-json

I am using the spray json library for json formatting in scala. I followed the instruction [here](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types) to build a jsonformatter with custom types like this:

```
class Listing(val attr1:String,
              val attr2:String,
                    ...
              val attr35:String)

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit object ListingJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Listing] {
    def write(l: Listing) =
      JsArray(
         JsString(l.attr1),
         JsString(l.attr2),
              ...
         JsString(l.attr35))
    def read(value: JsValue) = value match {
      case JsArray(Vector(
           JsString(attr1),
           JsString(attr2),
            ...
           JsString(attr35))) =>
        new Listing(attr1, attr2, attr3, ..., attr35)
      case _ => deserializationError("Listing expected")
    }
  }
}

import MyJsonProtocol._

val json = Listing("red","dress","polka dot", ..., "clothing").toJson
val listing = json.convertTo[Listing]
```

However, I'm getting this error:
`error: too many arguments for unapply pattern, maximum = 22`

Is there a way to parse and format more than 22 json attributes?

Comment: Do you have the Json with List of fixed size attribute `35`? Are what is the your input ,?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [kebs](https://github.com/theiterators/kebs) library - it uses Scala macros to create JSON formats for you.

Here is example for case class with more than 22 fields:
https://github.com/theiterators/kebs/blob/fa9994086aac7eadd63c09c67e389a77c22beef7/spray-json/src/test/scala/SprayJsonFormatTests.scala#L161

Answer (score -1):

Try [jsoniter-scala](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) - it supports more than 10K fields for a case class.

Here is a [test for 100 required fields](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/dc0e790832e5725960253c3f51d363760a7de230/macros/src/test/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/macros/JsonCodecMakerSpec.scala#L840-L867).

Also this library has great performance characteristics, here are results of benchmarks which compare it vs. Jackson, Circe and Play-JSON libraries using JDK 8: http://jmh.morethan.io/?source=https://plokhotnyuk.github.io/jsoniter-scala/oraclejdk8.json